# Change CSS in html table using JavaScript if/else

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to add in advance that i have just started coding and this is my first project in html/php/js (Until now, I've only really worked with C#).
I am currently writing a code that displays a mssql table inside a php/html file (I connected to the DB using PHP and displayed the table using html).
Now I need the different elements to change backgrond color if they exceed certain values.
For this to work, I first have to change the data types into integers and then compare them inside an `if`/`else`statement (or so I believe).
I already have a reload function (using JavaScript) so they colors would need to change after the page has been reloaded.

I already have a reload function (using JavaScript) so the colors would need to change after the page has been reloaded.

I edited my code to be able to show it to you. Hope this clear most of the confusions.

This is the JS part:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    // reload every 3 seconds

    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.reload();
    }, 3000);

    // if the page is not reloading, it should get reloaded automatically (the reload function stops after some time)
    start: while (true) {
      const pageAccessedByReload = (
        (window.performance.navigation && window.performance.navigation.type === 1) ||
        window.performance
        .getEntriesByType('navigation')
        .map((nav) => nav.type)
        .includes('reload')
      );

      if (!pageAccessedByReload) {
        location.reload();
        continue start;
        break;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }

    parseInt('var_1', 10);

    const element = document.querySelector('var_1');
    if ('var_1' < 1) {
      alert("ok");
    }
  </script>
```

This is the CSS part:

```css
<style>
    table {
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid;
    }
    
    th {
      font-size: large;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
```

And this is my html/php part:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>

</head>

<body style="margin: 50px;">
  <h1>test</h1>
  <br>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>var_1</th>
        <th>var_2</th>
        <th>var_3</th>
        <th>var_4</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <?php
          $serverName = "srvtest";
          $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DB", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"***", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
          $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
          
          if( !$conn ) 
          {
               echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
               die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
          }
          $sql = 'select * from view_test order by cast(Line as int) asc';
          $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
          
          while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
          {
               echo "<tr>
               <td>" .$row['var_1']. "</td>
               <td>" .$row['var_2']. "</td>
               <td>" .$row['var_3']. "</td>
               <td>" .$row['var_4']. "</td>
                              </tr>";
          }
          ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is `'xyz'`? please add a part of html as well.

Comment: what does "xyz' refer to

Comment: what is the value of xyz man are they number or string?

Comment: Use css variables [Using CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)